# Right coset equal to left coset

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G=\{ \tau_{ab}\mid a \neq 0, a \in\Bbb R\}$, $(x)\tau_{ab}= ax+b$, and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ such that $H = \{  \tau_{ab}\mid a \neq 0, a \in\Bbb Q\}$. I am asked to prove that a left coset of $H$ in $G$ is a right coset of $H$ in $G.$

My attempt: a right coset is of the form $ \tau_{ab}h$ where $h \in H$ , $h=\tau_{rs}, r \in\Bbb Q$ The image of $x$ under this mapping is $arx+ab+s$.
How can we equate this to a left coset of $H$ in $G$?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Answer (score 1):

Your notation is a bit unclear, so let me know if I've misunderstood. I assume you mean the group of affine transformations on $\mathbb{R}$.

Recall that given $g \in G$ and $H \leq G$, $gH = Hg \leftrightarrow gHg^{-1} = H$. Now let $t_{ab} \in H$ as you define it above. We just need to show that given $g = t_{cd} \in G$ that $t_{cd} \circ t_{ab} \circ t^{-1}_{cd} \in H$ and that this is a bijective map.

This is now just a straight forward calculation. Noting $t^{-1}_{cd} = t_{1/c,-d/c}$, we just calculate the map above (I'll let you fill in the details) giving   $t'(x) = ax + (bc + d - ad)$, where $t'$ is the resulting map from the composition. Is this in $H$? Since $H$ is defined as the group of affine transformations with rational $a$, then letting $t_{ab'}$ with $b' = bc + d - ad$, then $t_{ab'} \in H$ so that for any $g \in G$, $H$ is closed under conjugation. Furthermore, $b \mapsto b' = bc + d - ad$ is a bijection since $c \neq 0$, so $gHg^{-1} = H$ so left and right cosets are equal.